# Semantic-ui: determine if checkbox is checked or not

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

My code is using the semantic-ui checkbox module. I have four checkboxes. The code needs to determine when all the chekboxes are unchecked.

Html for one of the checkboxes:

```
<div class="inline field">
  <div class="ui toggle checkbox insurance">
    <input type="checkbox" name="insurance">
      <label>Would You Like To Reduce Your Monthly Insurance Costs</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var $services = $('.service-selection').find('.ui.checkbox'),
    $userData = $('.user-data');

function updateElements(elem, show) {
    ...

    // show second segment only when atleast one service checkbox is checked
    if ($services.filter(":checked").size() > 0) {
        $userData.removeClass('hidden');
    }
    else {
        $userData.addClass('hidden');
    }

}

$services.checkbox({
    'onEnable': function() {updateElements(this, true)},
    'onDisable': function() {updateElements(this, false)}
});
```

Turns out that semantic-ui does not actually set the `checked` attribute of corresponding `input` element. So the `:checked` selector fails.

My question is how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the services selector(`$services`), you need to in the input element within the `.ui.checkbox` element

```
var $services = $('.service-selection').find('.ui.checkbox input')
```

also `.size()` is deprecated use `.length`

```
if ($services.filter(":checked").length > 0) {
    $userData.removeClass('hidden');
}
else {
    $userData.addClass('hidden');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplest way for do it.

Let us imagine that a checkbox is used to enable or disable a text field. So we have:

```
# Using CoffeeScript:
$("#signature_credit_with_coupon").on "change", ->
  if (@checked)
    $('#signature_coupon').attr 'disabled', false
    $('#signature_coupon').focus()
  else
    $('#signature_coupon').attr 'disabled', true
  return

# Using JavaScript with jQuery:
$("#signature_credit_with_coupon").on("change", function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#signature_coupon').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#signature_coupon').focus();
  } else {
    $('#signature_coupon').attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

This works fine.